# How can I tell which Google account generated a 2 factor auto text triggered by a 3rd party hacker?

Tags: google-account, multi-factor-auth

I just got a 2 factor auto code sent to my phone, which means someone is trying to login to one my Google accounts, but I don't know which one as I have my phone setup as the 2 factor auto number for about 30 different Google accounts, linked to a range of business email addresses via Google apps for business as well as my standard Google personal account.

It seems someone knows the password to one of the account (we use a password manager so they only have one password not all of them at least) but how can I tell which account out of my 30 requested the 2 factor auto code ?

Comment: @pnuts I haven't Yet i was wondering if there was a simpler way but if not I'll have to

Comment: @pnuts in this instance it turned out to be a colleague setting up access to one of their accounts on a new device. For future ref is there something i could setup so that instead of just an alert saying "Your google auth code is 000000" it would say "Your google auth code for s***m@**** is 000000" so i would at least know which account it was related to ?